# Что лучше использовать и в какой ситуации: Dojo или jQuery?

Tags: jquery, svg, dojo, javascript

Доброй ночи! Не ради холивара хочу задать такой вопрос: "Что лучше использовать и в какой ситуации: **Dojo** или **jQuery**?" Точно могу сказать одно, если вам нужно работать с SVG графикой с помощью *JavaScript*, лучше использовать библиотеку Dojo.

Очень хочу услышать мнение профессионалов. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: [10 Reasons Why Your Projects Should Use the Dojo Toolkit](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/10-reasons-why-your-projects-should-use-the-dojo-toolkit/)

Comment: Вот фреймверк для работы с вектором http://raphaeljs.com/

Comment: Это я не то чтобы советую какой использовать, а просто если ты не знаешь raphaeljs, то тебе будет полезно знать